# multiprocessing iteration through each line of text file per thread for login

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to python/coding so please bare with me :)

I have this code which is working but I would like it to iterate through each line of the text file per thread for e.g.

Thread 1 using line 1 of the text file to login. Thread 2 using line 2 of the text file to login. Thread 3 using line 3 of the text file to login Instead of using line 1 for all three threads. I would then like to loop this through the rest of the text file until finish. Would appreciate any help. Thanks a lot

```
    def do_something():
       from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
       driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,executable_path="C:/Users/...")
    
    username_password_list = list()
    with open("userpass.txt") as file:
        for details in file:
            username1, password1 = details.split(':')
            username_password_list.append((username1, password1))
    for username1, password1 in username_password_list:
            driver.get('http://......')
            username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-username"]')
            username.send_keys(username1)
            password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]')
            password.send_keys(password1)
            login = driver.find_element_by_id('login-button')
            login.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)

    p1.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p3.start()
```

Comment: your code isn't indented properly

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new process every iteration and pass in that line.

```
def do_something():
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


    username_password_list = list()
    with open("userpass.txt") as file:
        for details in file:
            username1, password1 = details.split(':')
            username_password_list.append((username1, password1))
    for username1, password1 in username_password_list:
        multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(username1,password1)).start()
        time.sleep(1)



def thread_function(username1,password1):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path="C:/Users/...")
    driver.get('http://......')
    username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-username"]')
    username.send_keys(username1)
    password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-password"]')
    password.send_keys(password1)
    login = driver.find_element_by_id('login-button')
    login.click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for you reply. I've tried that and 1 chrome instance is opened, but doesn't do anything.....

Comment: trying to get it to just lop through the text file and respawn threads (browsers) until the end of the text file

Comment: My mistake, you need to include the driver in the ```thread_function``, ` I've edited it

Comment: I couldn't get it to work unfortunately from this, the chrome instances were just white. This explains a bit more on what exactly I'm wanting....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386391/iterating-through-each-line-of-multiple-text-files-unique-to-each-thread-in-pyt